# Как сделать exception message на русском?

Tags: c#, .net, исключения

Студия 2015/2010 английская версия.
Интересует именно возможность вывода сообщения на русском языке.
Возможно вывод только определенной группы исключений ну это в прицепе не принципиально.

```
 try
 {
     //капец!!!
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
```

Comment: Зачем, если можно так: MessageBox.Show("Шеф, фсе пропало!!!")

Comment: Можно конечно. Но хотелось бы чтоб пользователь видел что произошло и на русском.

Comment: Пользователь не должен видеть ваши исключения, вы должны их обработать, а пользователю выдать удобоваримый результат. И да, отлавливать чохом в одном кэтче все исключения плохая практика.

Comment: не спорю это я так для наглядности вопроса написал код.Но программа простая отлавливать перечислять все возможны исключения не вижу смысла.Вот и хотел в случаи чего выводить описания ошибки на русском.(русскоязычный пользователь быстрей сможет исправить эту ошибку если там конечно не требуется править код для исправления)

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? Суть вообще не ясна. Если при выводе русского сообщения вылетает ошибка - дайте ее для изучения. На сферическом коне в вакууме шаманить и предсказывать поведение программ не умеем.

Comment: @FORTRAN, поймите очень простую штуку пользователь вообще не должен видеть ваших исключений, это просто ...стыдно для вас.

Comment: @Сергей, он спрашивает, как вывести локализованное сообщение о произвольном исключении.

Comment: @Mirdin, пользователь должен видеть то, что должен. И нечего над ним издеваться выводя сообщения в духе "что-то случилось, сходите к админу".

Comment: В любом случаи вопрос не про выводить/не выводить сообщения/когда выводить/логировать/не логировать, а про скажем так русификацию сообщения исключения.

Comment: @Qwertiy, пользователь должен видеть только то, что вы ему показываете, а не внутренности вашей программы. Или вы думаете что "девушке-бухгалтеру" будет особо интересно читать о некоректности соединения с базой данных, когда на самом деле ей таки надо пойти к администратору и получить недостающие права.

Comment: @Qwertiy, если он говорит об этом, я хочу увидеть ошибку которая возникает при попытки отправки такого исключения, потому, что у меня нет никакого желания качать IDE его версии и проверять в чем проблема. Если у него есть проблема с этим, пусть подробнее опишет.

Comment: @Сергей, не возникает ошибка при отправке исключения. Есть программа. Где-то происходит исключение. Любое исключение. Где-то ещё он его ловит. Дальше он хочет вывести пользователю сообщение об ошибке на конкретном языке. Причём перевод он хочет от .net'а или системы. Если всё ещё непонятно, см. ответ Athari.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Текст исключения будет выводиться на русском языке, если у пользователя установлена русификация .Net Framework. В противном случае - текст  будет выводиться на английском. Попробуйте установить русификатор и исключения в студии тоже станут выводиться на русском.

Comment: @Qwertiy, у человека та же проблема, что и у меня - не может нормально объяснить. В такой формулировке я вообще о другом подумал.

Comment: @Сергей, я просто видел сообщения на разных языках? так что сразу понял, о чём идёт речь :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вас интересуют сообщения в исключениях, которые генерирует .NET Frameowrk, то обратите внимание на свойство `Thread.CurrentUICulture`. Например, следующая программа:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ru-ru");
try {
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
try {
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

выведет следующий текст:

```
Операция является недопустимой из-за текущего состояния объекта.
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

Текущая локаль по умолчанию берётся из настроек системы, то есть соответствует языку UI в Windows. Обычно менять это значение не следует, в этом случае пользователь видит текст на том языке, который предпочитает. Если ваше приложение многоязыковое, то вы можете менять локаль UI в зависимости от текущего языка в вашем приложении (а вот `Thread.CurrentCulture` лучше не трогать).

Comment: т.е. на винде с выбраненным русским будут ошибки на русском?

Comment: @FORTRAN Да.​​​

Comment: Это может не сработать, если исключение бросается не в том потоке, в котором ловится. Например, `try { await ThrowExceptionAsync(); } catch (Exception e) { /* oops */ }`.

Comment: @VladD На этот случай есть `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`.

Comment: ... это если вы контролируете фреймворк. В случае какого-нибудь ASP.NET ваш код просто выполняется в каком-то рабочем потоке.

Comment: Я предполагаю, что при отсутствии установленного русификатора .Net Framework такой способ не прокатит.

Comment: @Vlad "Русификатор" как-то отдельно ставится? Я вручную дотнет уже давно не ставил, он вместе со всей системой обновляется. Я предполагал, что дотнет в этом отношении подчиняется языку системы и ставится соответствующий.

Comment: @Athari, да. он отдельным пакетом ставится. и все сообщения об исключениях начинают выводиться на русском. У нас на работе этот пакет с обновлениями windows подтягивается. приходится сносить и добавлять в исключения.

Comment: @Vlad Я поступил проще: у меня вся винда на английском. ;)

Comment: Так у меня тоже. Это, видимо, связано с политикой обновлений на предприятии. :)

Answer (score 11):

Исключения *не предназначены* для показа пользователю. Текст исключения не локализуем, содержит техническую информацию, содержит форматирование, интересное программисту, а не пользователю. Он может выдать секретную или приватную информацию, которую вы вовсе не планировали показывать пользователю. Самое ужасное — текст исключения не помогает пользователю выйти из проблемной ситуации, он лишь описывает *непосредственную* причину ошибки в терминах технических подробностей случившегося, а не в терминах того, что нужно *на самом деле* пользователю, и что он сделал не так (или что пошло не так).

Поэтому никогда (то есть действительно **никогда**) не выводите пользователю в UI текст исключения.

Как делать правильно? В случае, если ваша модель произвела исключение, вы должны определить причину ошибки в терминах вашей задачи, понятных пользователю, и конвертировать это в объект, представляющий нестандартную ситуацию. Затем ваша бизнес-логика должна запустить процедуру информирования пользователя о случившемся и возможно автоматической реакции на него.

Например, если при чтении конфигурационного файла возникла ошибка, связанная с тем, что доступ к файлу запрещён, или что в файле не найдем валидный XML, или что значение `"привет земляне"` не может быть преобразовано к типу `int` и не может быть значением атрибута `version.major` — всё это неинтересно пользователю. Ваш код должен сказать, что инсталляция программы испорчена, и её нужно восстановить, или (ещё лучше!) проинформировать пользователя, что произведена успешная попытка сброса испорченной конфигурации программы.

Это должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
try
{
    await model.ApplySettings();
    return;
}
catch (InvalidSettingsException e)
{
    Logger.Log(e);
    // для старых версий .NET вам придётся вынести await за catch
    var corrected = await model.TryRepairSettings();
    if (corrected)
    {
        await PresentSettingsCorrected();
    }
    else
    {
        await PresentSettingsUncorrectable();
        throw new UnrecoverableSettingsError(e);
    }
}
```

Локализацией сообщения займётся процедура `PresentSettingsCorrected` (и `PresentSettingsUncorrectable`) обычным образом, как и любая другая процедура, ответственная за взаимодействие с пользователем.

Код

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

— преступление. Никогда так не делайте. Программа, написанная так, всеми и всегда будет считаться студенческой поделкой.

---

С другой стороны, *логирование* подавленного исключения (вместе с цепочкой вложенных исключений) — это практически обязанность программиста. Вам эта информация пригодится, когда что-то на машине пользователя пойдёт не так. Вы можете даже написать мелкую функциональность по автоматической упаковке в архив и отправке на ваш адрес свежих логов (разумеется, спросив предварительно явного согласия пользователя на это).

---

(*вынес из комментариев*) Правильная реакция на ошибочные ситуации — очень важная задача, и притом непростая. Обычно при прототипировании приложения на обработке ошибок экономят время, потому что главное на этом этапе — показать функциональность, работающую «когда всё в порядке». Потом встраивание логики обработки ошибок становится сложнее, ведь она превращает линейное течение логики программы в разветвлённое.

На самом деле в UI-приложении экранов, обслуживающих ошибочные ситуации, может быть и столько же, сколько экранов для нормального течения программы! Поэтому на правильную обработку таких ситуаций придётся потратить время, сравнимое с временем разработки основной логики приложения.

К сожалению, часто этим пренебрегают даже крупные производители ПО, в результате чего мы и видим беспомощные сообщения об ошибках в стиле «Произошло что-то ужасное, я падаю» или «Вот вам текст исключения, разбирайтесь сами». Пользователи часто выносят своё мнение о программе по таким вот недоделкам. Которые, на мой вкус, и отличают хорошо, с любовью сделанный проект от закодированного на коленке прототипа.

Comment: "всё это неинтересно пользователю. Ваш код должен сказать, что инсталляция программы испорчена, и её нужно восстановить" - ну супер! Знаешь как достали порграммы, работающие по принципу Запустить - "Неизвестная ошибка". Установить - "Сначала удалите установленную версию". Удалить - "Ошибка. Удаление невозможно." И чего с ними делать такимми красивыми? У меня их уже штук 5 накопилось!

Comment: Ну это уже дело каждого разработчика какой именно текст ошибки показывать пользователю. Главное чтобы пользователь не видел непосредственно текст исключения.

Comment: В общем случае показывать сообщение любого исключения (`catch (Exception)`) — не самая здравая идея, согласен. Однако если точно знаешь, какое исключение ловишь, то выдать текст сообщения исключения — не такое уж и преступление (хотя, конечно, и не лучшее решение для серьёзного продукта). Скажем, если в консольном приложении я запрашиваю путь к файлу, то выдать текст *"Could not find file 'C:\autoexec.bat'."* — вполне нормально. Причём это сделано будет на языке пользователя, что позволяет простым и дешёвым способом локализовать простое приложение. Простые утилиты не только студенты пишут.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Потому что это только вы программист, и можете из программистского мумбо-юмбо вытащить для себя какой-то смысл. Представьте себе, что ваш автомобиль вместо «необходимо заправиться» выдал бы вам «subcritical value at sensor unit B58/X-314159». Точно так же текст исключения будет воспринят обыкновенным, живым пользователем.

Comment: @Athari: Это в том счастливом случае, когда текст исключения хорошо ложится на problem domain (и вы можете управлять его локализацией!). А что делать с `Int32.Parse` и текстом "Input string was not in a correct format."? Пользователь не вводил никакую строку, что он сделал неправильно и как ему реагировать на такое?

Comment: Пользователю не нужны технические подробности. [Нет, правда.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/03/27/9512420.aspx)

Comment: @VladD Если консольное приложение выдаёт парой имя параметра и исключение при его интерпретации, то даже такое бестолковое сообщение исключения может быть полезнее, чем сообщение на французском для английского юзера.

Comment: @VladD Сообщение "subcritical value at sensor unit B58/X-314159" или хотя бы код HRESULT будет в разы полезнее, чем "Неизвестная ошибка", потому что пользователь хотя бы будет знать, какую строчку вбивать в гугл, на SuperUser будет меньше бестолковых вопросов без достаточной информации, а службе поддержки не нужно будет мучительно описывать, как добраться до хитро запрятанных логов. Часто сочетание "(имя приложения) + (текст странной ошибки)" очень точно идентифицирует проблему, что позволяет быстро найти решение в гугле. Этим особенно винда славится.

Comment: @Athari: Не, «Неизвестная ошибка» — это всё равно что расписаться в собственном бессилии. Впрочем, HRESULT тоже. Потому что гуглить сообщение об ошибке будут только компьютерные энтузиасты, а остальные просто ещё раз убедятся в том, что computers are hard to use.

Comment: @VladD Вы исходите из предположения об идеальных приложениях, создающихся на бесконечных ресурсах. А в жизни всё бывает далеко не так. Конечно, в идеале нужно рассматривать все варианты, но, как показала практика, checked exceptions не работают. Скажем, если вы будете писать приложение, работающее с конфигом, то вы будете обрабатывать все эти ситуации и писать в исключении детальные инструкции по исправлению? Ошибка чтения файла конфига, запрет на чтение файла, запрет на запись файла, (...)

Comment: @VladD (...) все мыслимые и немыслимые виды повреждения файла (формат, целостность, превышение допустимого диапазона...), невозможность загрузки из-за уровней безопасности, заблокированность другим приложением (с указанием на конкретный процесс)... Если вы не пишете что-то убер-надёжное, то, скорее всего, вы выполните сериализацию-десериализацию и сообщите "Не могу прочитать файл" или "Не могу записать файл" — в лучшем случае. И вот в этом случае я таки призываю конкатенировать сообщение из исключения или прятать его за кнопкой "дополнительно" — авось там окажется что-то вразумительное.

Comment: @VladD, во-первых, я не говорил, что надо показывать исключение как есть. Я говорил, что надо показать адекватное сообщение и можно показать дополнительную кнопку "Подробная информация" или "Техническая информация". Захочет человек разбираться - нажмёт и подумает, не захочет - не нажмёт. Ошибку можно кинуть в гугл, можно задать вопрос на форуме. А вот с ошибкой по типу "Что-то случилось, приложение будет закрыто" сделать вообще ничего нельзя. И даже техподдержка выдаёт только: "Попробуйте переустановить windows" Вот пример: http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=45640

Comment: @Athari: Это да, ресурсы ограничены. Поэтому обычно будет сообщение «Установка повреждена, нажмите |здесь| для запуска автоматической исправлялки.» Но мне кажется, что вы неявно считаете, что ресурсы надо направлять на функциональность, а не на вылизывание интерфейса. К сожалению, это не так: для нормального пользователя вылизанный интерфейс важнее хороших алгоритмов. (Разумеется, в известных пределах, да.)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Я разумеется против беззубого «что-то непонятное случилось»: это точно такой же признак лени и нежелания продумать стратегию борьбы с исключительными ситуациями, как и выдача голого текста исключения.

Comment: @VladD, ситуация "что-то непонятное случилось" в любом случае возможна. И хорошо бы, чтобы хоть кто-то по ней смог понять, что именно случилось.

Comment: Давайте-ка я подчеркну: правильная реакция на ошибочные ситуации очень важна и очень сложна. Ей часто пренебрегают, потому что практически никто не умеет делать это правильно. А юзеры обычно выносят своё мнение о программе по её реакции на ошибочные ситуации. Такова жизнь

Comment: @Qwertiy: Я как раз написал в предпоследней части ответа. Для этого нужны логи + кнопка «упаковать/послать инфу для разработчиков». Заставлять юзера гуглить — признак неумения фиксить баги.

Comment: @VladD, кроме разработчиков есть и другие люди, способные помочь. И гугл. Или по-твоему разработчики должны каждому наткнувшемуся на ошибку объяснять, как её исправить? Особенно, если это ошибка, связанная с неправильными действиями пользователя? Что плохого дать пользователю возможность увидеть подробные сведения? Именно возможность, а не обязанность.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Нет такого понятия «ошибочные действия пользователя». Есть «действия, которые программист не предусмотрел из-за лени или нехватки времени». Разработчики не должны ничего объяснять, они должны выпустить апгрейд, в котором проблема не возникает вовсе.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Проблемы в этом нет как таковой. Проблема есть лишь в том, что _большинству пользователей это не поможет_, т. к. они не будут тратить своё время на отладку твоей или моей программы. Если ты пишешь программу только для энтузиастов и не собираешься её продавать, ты можешь плюнуть на желание большинства не заморачиваться. Если ты пишешь для людей и не под десктопный линукс — тебе придётся решить проблему за юзера, он за это и платит.

Comment: @VladD В первую очередь я говорю об экзотических ошибках. Скажем, если у юзера неадекватно расставлены права на папках и ветках реестра, но вполне себе оттестированные виндовые инсталляторы запросто могут обрушиться с ошибкой "какая-то фигня произошла". А ошибки, которые возникают постоянно (юзер ввёл что-то странное в какое-то поле в гуе) — это да, это обязательно обрабатывать тщательно, это приоритет.

Comment: @VladD Ну и от частоты возникновения ошибок зависит. Скажем, мне пришлось в консольную утилиту для конвертации файлов добавлять проверку, что у файла нет метки "скачан из интернета", хотя мне бы в голову не пришло добавлять нечто подобное. Но проблема возникает, и возникает часто, чтоб её. И ведь это не какое-то приложение с гламурными кнопочками, это инстурмент для продвинутых пользователей.

Comment: @Athari: Тогда, думаю, мы по существу согласны друг с другом.

Comment: @VladD, большинство пользователей не сделает чего-то, что дестабилизирует работу программы. А вот как раз тем, кто сделает, это вероятно поможет. Залез человек в службы, какую-то отключил, а программа без неё работать не может. Должна ли она обрабатывать ошибку, что служба отключена? При том, что отключить её мог только пользователь намеренно. Поможет ли такому пользователю сообщение с кодом? Вероятно да - раз он уже куда-то лазил и что-то делал, то он сможет понять, что пошло не так. Надо ли предусматривать многосимвольные разделители целой и дробной части? А различные для денег и для чисел?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Сделают, к сожалению. Например, выставят системный язык, не предусмотренный программистом (таким часто бывает русский, да). Ну и по твоему примеру: программа не имеет права полагаться на наличие запущенной службы, это явный баг. Если он не обнаружился при разработке, а всплыл на машине юзера, надо быстро-быстро выпустить автоапдейт. А с запятой как десятичным разделителем проблемы бывают очень часто :) И это вина программистов. Так что надо не давать юзеру возможность задобрить программу, а взять и пофиксить баги.

Answer (score 3):

1. Надо ловить только те исключения, которые являются ожидаемыми.
2. Надо *логировать* исключение целиком (а не только Message).
3. Пользователю можно показывать какое-либо сообщение, а не Message.
4. Если возникло неожиданное исключение, пользователю можно сообщить о неизвестной ошибке (при этом в логе всё равно должна быть полная информация).

PS: Если бы речь шла о программе для себя, вопрос о локализации информации об исключениях не возник бы, да?

---

> Но программа простая отлавливать перечислять все возможны исключения не вижу смысла.

А должен видеть.

1. Именно на основе типа исключения надо понимать, что пошло не так, что делать и что сообщать пользователю. Message вообще не обязательно содержит информацию об ошибке - например, полезная информация может содержаться во вложенном исключении.
2. Отлов всех исключений не даёт даже нормально код при написании отлаживать. Я уже правил чей-то замечательный код, в котором охапка вызовов на пару сотен строк в сумме обёрнута в catch(Exception) с выводом "Ошибка открытия файлов", а я код редактирую, у меня там в рандомных местах ошибки.
3. Для необработанных исключений следует использовать специальный хэндлер.

---

> В любом случаи вопрос не про выводить/не выводить сообщения/когда выводить/логировать/не логировать, а про скажем так русификацию сообщения исключения.

Надо перехватывать конкретный тип исключения, по нему показывать соответствующее сообщение на нужном языке (которое не связано с Message).

Если предполагается, что пользователи будут продвинутыми, можно добавить кнопку для отображения подробной информации об исколючении, где уже вывести `ex.ToString()` (а не `ex.Message`).

Comment: ну да. То есть есть простая прога и нужно выводить описания ошибки на русском языке. Основные исключения я  отловлю.Вот хотелось бы как то выводить на русском чтобы пользователь мог сам устранить ошибку.

Comment: @FORTRAN Интересно, как пользователь сможет сам починить `AccessViolation` или `NullReference`

Answer (score 2):

У пользователя должен быть установлен [языковой пакет](http://net-framework.ru/) для .Net Framework. Тогда все сообщения будут выводиться на русском.